# How can I get a dynamic XHTML file that has an .xml suffix to work properly in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xhtml

Is there any way of getting Firefox to open a dynamic, local XHTML file that has an .xml suffix, and treat it as if it had an .html or .xhtml suffix?

I've developed a process where our editors export BOM structures from our PLM system as XHTML. The PLM software automatically launches Firefox upon export, and a JavaSript loaded by the XHTML checks the BOM structure for errors, and outputs (using appendChild) the error messages in a table in a "console" div.

But, the latest version of our PLM software now enforces an .xml suffix on all exported files, regardless of it's contents.

I don't want to make the editors have to change the suffix manually, as this process is repeated hundreds of times daily.

So, I'm testing some files to see how Firefox will handle them with the .xml extension, and they're holding up pretty well.

But there is one noticeable area of concern, which is the "console" error table. It's the only content that I'm adding dynamically, and it's getting treated a bit differently than the essential content.

Firstly, each table row in the console was displaying inline. I think I discovered [why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=control#Summary). And I was able to fix this very easily by explicitly setting console table rows to "display: block" in my CSS.

Secondly, the onclick that I add to each row in the console (that calls a function which highlights the location of the error in the document) no longer works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function highlightItem(elementId) {
                document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
            function outputToConsole(message, elementId) {
                var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
                var newCell = document.createElement('td');
                var newText = document.createTextNode(message);
                newRow.appendChild(newCell);
                newCell.appendChild(newText);
                newRow.onclick = function () {
                    return highlightItem(elementId);
                }
                var consoleBody = document.getElementById('consoleBody');
                consoleBody.appendChild(newRow);
            }
            function checkDocument() {
                // Check myDoc for blah
                var myDocElements = document.querySelectorAll('#myDoc p');
                for (var i = 0; i &lt; myDocElements.length; i++) {
                    if (myDocElements[i].textContent.match(/blah/gi)) {
                        outputToConsole('Element ' + myDocElements[i].id + ' contains the word blah', myDocElements[i].id);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkDocument()">
        <div id="myDoc">
            <p id="1">Blah blah blah.</p>
            <p id="2">This is some text.</p>
            <p id="3">This is some more blah text.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="console">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="message"/>
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Document Check</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="consoleBody">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows how to fix my JavaScript so that it works, or how to tell Firefox to treat [local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XML_in_Mozilla#XHTML) .xml files as application/xhtml+xml, or has any other bright ideas that could help me out, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could put your parsing logic in another html file with its own javascript, and load in the XML files separately and update your html page with the data components from the XML?  I would want to make sure I could host my html on the same server so cross-origin doesn't become an issue.

Comment: Another option, if you are able to add elements to the exported XML, would be to include a [reference to a XSL file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757904(v=vs.85).aspx) that you build, such that the XSLT transforms the XML into HTML.  That would display the resulting HTML rather than the XML when the XML file is loaded in a browser.

Comment: As for your second suggestion, would the same MIME-type/DOM confusion that Firefox is having not still apply in this scenario? I mean, that's what I'm already doing. I'm converting these BOM structures to valid XHTML using XSLT, but within the PLM software. Thing is, now I can't use an extension that compliments the content and hence why I think Firefox might be getting confused.

Comment: Chrome doesn't mind, it successfully transforms into html when I load a xml url (I think it has to be on a web server, not a local or network filesystem).  I don't have firefox for testing.  Try placing the example.xml and xsl files from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/Basic_Example) on your server and see if Firefox does OK (you would use the url of the XML file).  If so then that's a valid option.

Comment: Thanks James! That looks like the solution I need! I took the XSL I was using to transform the structure to XHTML within the PLM system, and put it in the destination directory. I exported the structure in it's raw XML form, opened it up, pasted the example processing instruction at the top of it, and changed the href to point to my XSL. It seems to work perfectly. All I need to do now is switch out the XSL in the PLM system with one that simply adds the processing instruction. As an added bonus, I no longer need to involve PLM-support when I need to update the XSL. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey great, glad you got it solved.

Comment: Maybe a little late to the party, but I can't get Firefox to behave differently between XHTML files that have .xhtml or .xml extensions. I mean, any working XHTML file I can rename to .xml and  it will keep working the same. So, I am curious what went wrong in your situation.

Comment: Mr Lister, I've updated the code above to include a complete example. I'm using Firefox 54 (32-bit) on Windows 7. (Also, please note that the file is locally loaded, not served.) I'm going to stick with doing the XSLT in-browser, as it has it's advantages. But I manage a number of intranet web apps, and if an alternate/elementary solution to this problem exists I'm also curious to discover what it is.